# Best way to distribute script with low friction

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I have helped a few friends recently with fixing a problem on OS X and I would like to turn it in to a script so I can send it to people instead of walking them through it. It consists of two steps:

- delete a file
- restart the computer

What is the best way to package this so people will be able to execute it with the default security settings on Mountain Lion and Mavericks? AppleScript, Automator, Shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppleScript is imho the best one for your case. Shell needs `sudo` for `shutdown -r` and automator is overkill for these basic needs.

Here are the 2 basic scripts you'll need :

To reboot :

```
tell application "Finder"
  restart
end tell
```

To delete a file :

```
tell application "Finder" to delete file "path:to:file"
```

If you want to use a posix path, an alternative to the previous one is

```
tell application "Finder" to delete POSIX path of "/path/to/file"
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I need to find the file based on a pattern, something I might normally use `ls` or a regexp for?

Comment: You can call shell scripts within AppleScript using `do shell script`.